# FCM Android data message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving the notification message even if the app is in the background, but whenever a notification is received it automatically opens the activity (even if the user doesn't click on the notification).

My `onMessageReceived` is

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    if (data.containsKey("click_action")) {
        if(data.containsValue("postlike") || data.containsValue("comment") || data.containsValue("newpost")){
            b.putString("PostId", data.get("post_id").toString());
            Firebase_Action_Click.startActivity(data.get("click_action"), b, this);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentText(data.get("body"))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

And in my `Firebase_Action_Click`

```
public static void startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context) {
    Class cls = null;
    try {
        cls = Class.forName(className);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        //means you made a wrong input in firebase console
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
    i.putExtras(extras);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

And in my launcher activity I have added these lines,

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.hasExtra("click_action")) {
        Firebase_Action_Click.startActivity(intent.getStringExtra("click_action"), intent.getExtras(), this);
    }
}
```

Everything goes fine but the only problem I face is even if the app is in the background and I get a notification it automatically opens the application.

I want the same action to be done only when the user clicks on the Notification.

Could anyone help me on this, Thanks in advance

Comment: what should this line do? Firebase_Action_Click.startActivity(data.get("click_action"), b, this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fires the `Activity` because you launch the `Activity` from the `onMessageReceived` function. So if you want to launch the `Activity` when you click on your Notification you may need to start the `Activity` as your `PendingIntent`.

I would like to recommend simple modification in your code. Your `startActivity` function in `Firebase_Action_Click` may return the `Intent` it has created and look like this.

```
public static Intent startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context) {
    Class cls = null;
    try {
        cls = Class.forName(className);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        //means you made a wrong input in firebase console
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
    i.putExtras(extras);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    return i; // Return the intent from here. 
}
```

Now in your `onMessageReceived` function, you need to set a `PendingIntent` too inside `if(data.containsValue("postlike") || data.containsValue("comment") || data.containsValue("newpost"))` - this if statement, like the one you set for the `else` part. So your code might look like this.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    if (data.containsKey("click_action")) {
        if(data.containsValue("postlike") || data.containsValue("comment") || data.containsValue("newpost")) {
            b.putString("PostId", data.get("post_id").toString());
            Intent intent = Firebase_Action_Click.startActivity(data.get("click_action"), b, this);

            // Now add the flags and create pendingIntent here
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentText(data.get("body"))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Now your notification system should work fine.